# move files based on content

Tags: text-processing, files

I want to move all files that contain a number greater than 25 (at least on one instance) but don't contain any number smaller than 25 after the string >*randomnumber*_xxx_ to a specific folder.

Example of a file that needs to be moved:

```
>23424_xxx_26
>331134_xxx_27
>6634_xxx_30
```

Example of a file that doesn't need to be moved:

```
>22234_xxx_20
>434534_xxx_27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the first issue is to detect the files that needs to be moved.

This could be done using `grep`:

```
grep -q -E '^>.*_(1?[0-9]|2[0-4])$'
grep -q -E '^>.*_(2[5-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3,})$'
```

These commands would return true if the input data contained a line that matched the given extended regular expressions.

The expression `_(1?[0-9]|2[0-4])$` would match any positive integer less than 25 occurring at the end of a line after an underscore, and `_(2[5-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3,})$` matches any positive integer greater than or equal to 25 at the end of the line after an underscore (assuming there are no zero-filled integers such as `002`).  We also match the `>` at the start of the line. The `-q` option would stop `grep` from actually *outputting* anything (we're only interested in whether we could find one of these lines or not).

For a file to be copied, the first `grep` must return *false* and the second `grep` must return *true*.

Applying this to each file of a directory (in this case regardless of what the files are called as you did not say anything about this):

```
for filename in ./*; do
    [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue

    if ! grep -q -E '^>.*_(1?[0-9]|2[0-4])$' "$filename" &&
         grep -q -E '^>.*_(2[5-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3,})$' "$filename"
    then
        mv -i "$filename" /some/destination
    fi
done
```

This would move the files that fulfil the requirements to some destination directory at `/some/destination`. The `-i` option to `mv` would cause the utility to ask for confirmation before overwriting an already existing file with the same name as the file being moved.

The first `[ ! -f ... ]` test in the loop would skip anything in the directory that is not a regular file (or a symbolic link to a regular file).

Comment: `echo 001 | grep -Ee "[0-9]{3,}"` it will match 001, which is less than 25.

Comment: @PRY With the added assumption about integers that are not zero-filled, I think this should be ok.